# Http interceptors for external urls

Tags: angularjs

I have written an http interceptor to add authentication tokens to every request. In my html when i click a link this interceptor is not called. Not sure why that is happening?

My interceptor code -

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.factory('httpAuthorizationInterceptor',['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            if (config.url.indexOf('login') == -1) {
                config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Session ' +<session_id>;
            }
            return config || $q.when(config);
        }
    };
}])
```

My html -

```
<a data-ng-href="http://example.com/view"></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your anchor tag will not actually make an ajax call, an `http` interceptors are for intercepting ajax calls made via angular. Clicking on that anchor tag will be like opening an URL in the browser.

In order to do the ajax call: you need to tweak the code in the following way:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

    var interceptor = [function() {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                if (config.url.indexOf('login') == -1) {
                    config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Session ' + <session_id>;
                }
                return config;
            }
        };
    }];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
}]);
```

And now your controller code will look like something:

```
$scope.doSomething = function() {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://example.com/view'}).then(function(data) {
        // success
    });
};
```

And your HTML code will be:

```
<a href="doSomething()"></a>
```

The only thing is that, the external url you are making ajax call is either be on the same domain or must support cross origin request.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks shashank. Can you please advise whats the best way to add the authorization tokens in this scenario. Do i need to write my own directive for an anchor tag.

Comment: Sure, what you actually want to do with that external url? Do you want to do ajax call on that or just wanted to open in another tab?

Comment: Shashank, I want to do an ajax call with that and pass the authorization token when i do the ajax call. I already have an http interceptor to pass the authorization token with each call. Currently I am writing a service which does the ajax call and that seems to work correctly. Not sure though its the best way

Comment: @EshwariChandrashekhar I've updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks @Shashank this is exactly what i ended up doing.